# How to get elements by setting a filter on their children attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I've got the following DOM structure:

```
<g class="box" rel="1">
    <text editable="false">some text</text>
</g>
<g class="box" rel="2">
    <text editable="true">some text</text>
</g>
<g class="box" rel="3">
    <text editable="false">some text</text>
</g>
<g class="box" rel="4">
    <text editable="true">some text</text>
</g>
```

What I want to do now is to get the g-elements where the children "editable" attribute is true.

I've tried this, but this seems not to do what I want:

```
var box = $('.box :last-child[editable="true"]').filter(':parent');
```

Hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('g.box text[editable="true"]').parent();
```

**OR**

```
$('text[editable="true"]').parent('g.box');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using jQuery -

```
$("g.box>text[editable='true']").parent();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there;

```
var box = $('.box text[editable=true]').parent();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var box = $('.box :last-child[editable="true"]').parent('g');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.box :last-child[editable="true"]').parent('g');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot easier to select the child and then get to the parent:

```
$('g.box text[editable=true]').parent()
```

This will select the parents with editable children

Hope this helps